Calling the set method of a persistent entity but changes are not written to the database
I am a beginner in hibernate, in my perisistent entity I have a function like this:
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

and I call it like this in another class:
class1.function1
abcs.forEach(abc -> abc.setStatus("WORKING"));

class2.function2
abcs.forEach(abc -> abc.setStatus("SUCCESS"));

but the abcs didn't be update in function2, they are still "WORKING" status, what might have happened here?
How to make abc change to "SUCCESS"?

@Transactional on a method in your entity won't do a thing. The method you are executing needs to be transactional (so the one getting the list and doing the changes).

I have @Transactional in class1.function1, could this have anything to do with it?

Without the real code and full code instead of snippets this is going to be impossible to answer. Nonetheless the fact remains that the method you are executing needs to be transactional so the overarching method.

please share your code
